# How do I remove my deployment instances created using Meteor Up?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, meteor, meteor-up

I've got a test Azure Ubuntu server that I'm testing deployments on.

I've created a number of instances of my Meteor app using Meteor Up.

I would like to remove them from the server.

Does Meteor up have some sort of "mup remove" command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sadly no, Meteor-up does not provide any automated way to clean up after itself. Basically you'd have to follow these steps, on your server:

1. Stop your app using `sudo service yourApp stop`. If not, your app will still be running even after deletion
2. Delete the **/opt/yourApp** folder: `sudo rm -rf /opt/yourApp`
3. Delete the init script: `sudo rm /etc/init/yourApp.cfg`

Also, if you used an external database, don't forget to clean it up using the mongo client:

```
> use yourDatabase
> db.dropDatabase()
```

Comment: ah, I think the step 3 is what I'm missing - what is this init script do?

Comment: It allows for meteor-up to start or stop the service

Comment: I had an app using SSL with Stud (via mup) and I'm noticing Stud still runs (correctly) with any new app deployed at my public domain.  Any ideas on how to stop Stud and/or where it gets initiated?

Comment: @evolross ssh onto your server and do `sudo stop stud`. Not sure where/how it gets started, but if you want to go exploring I'm sure it's in the [sourcecode](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) somewhere.